# Sorting a side by side bar graph based on one bar, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I am trying to create a side by side bar graph in ggplot2 sorted numerically by the left bar of the side by side graph. I've tried the reorder function, but that seems to sort by the average of the two bars and not just one of them.

Example side by side bar plot

```
library(ggplot2)

a<-(c(1:10))
e<-c("group a","group b", "group c", "group d", "group e", "group a","group b", "group c", "group d", "group e")
fillvariable<-c(1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1)
data<-cbind(a,e,fillvariable)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
data

plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=e, y=a,fill=factor(fillvariable))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge')

plot
```

I would like to sort the bars numerically by the left (red) bar (see sample bar graph). My real x axis has many groups so it would be less than idea to type each label and set the order that way. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this using a function in R?

I'm realizing that I am having another issue too. I'm sure how to make sure my bar plot puts the 1 fill factor on the left every time. Any advice for that would be appreciated as well.

[image: sample bar output]

Comment: Quick sidenote: a better way of doing `data<-cbind(a,e,fillvariable);
data<-as.data.frame(data)` is the singe line `data <- data.frame(a, e, fillvariable)`

Comment: If you fix your data.frame as Gregor pointed out, then the standard `reorder` should be fine: `plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=reorder(e,ifelse(fillvariable==2,0,a), FUN=max), y=a,fill=factor(fillvariable))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge')`

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I'll give your suggestion a try, MrFlick. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
# isolate the subset of data you want to order by
subset_to_order = subset(data, fillvariable == 1)
# use reorder to reorder the factor
subset_to_order$e = with(subset_to_order, reorder(e, a))

# apply the same order to the whole data
data$e = factor(data$e, levels = levels(subset_to_order$e))

plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=e, y=a,fill=factor(fillvariable))) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')
plot
```

[image]

MrFlick's comment shows a similar way. Basically your question is the same as the R-FAQ about [ordering bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5208679/903061), but with a twist that the order is determined by a subset of the data instead of the whole data. We use the same solution, adapting it to find a way to ignore the parts of the data that don't matter for the ordering. I did it with an explicit subset, MrFlick's comment does  it by zeroing out the other parts with `ifelse`. Both work just fine.

I've also switched your `geom_bar(stat = "identity") to`geom_col()`, which is preferred in the last few`ggplot` releases.

This does depend on not messing up the classes of your columns. When you use `cbind`, you implicitly convert to matrix which is bad when you mix numeric and string/factor columns. Keep it as a data frame and everything should be fine.

Comment: Also probably worth pointing out the existence of `geom_col` to replace `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` in these cases.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!